# REST service to return only current user-related resources

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a REST service implemented using Spring MVC (RestControllers) with token based security (using Spring Security). How can i filter resources depending on user identity? Let's say user has some reports. How can I let authorized user by performing a call to */reports* to see only **his** reports?

Obviously i can make userId to be a request parameter or path variable, but something tells me that this is a bad practice.

I assume i can achieve that using Spring Security features, but how exactly could i do that and, more important, where is the most appropriate place to apply such filtering? Should controllers perform calls to services passing user identity or should it be somehow retrieved at repositories level (I use Spring Data JPA)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Authentication` object whenever a user is successfully logged in.
It contains `Object principal` `Object credentials` and `Set authorities`.

All you need to do is override `UserDetailsService` to add new parameters for your authenticated user. Add your userId in authentication as [shown in blog](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/01/spring-security-adding-additional-details-to-principal-user-object.html)

Now when you do

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
    this will return you the User object of the spring security.
    You can get the user id from here and use this in controller to do necessary actions.

Comment: You dont need a session, as already mentioned security is maintained by rest impl, this is just a way to put custom data to a token.

Comment: Thanks! Ain't there a more elegant way to obtain user info? Using one of Spring Security annotations maybe? And where is the right place to do that? Controllers?

Comment: you way also want to have a look at [Json Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/). Yes this is the way to do in Spring Security acc to the docs. You can do it in either controller or even services since SecurityContextHolder is static in context.

Comment: Ok, so basically the idea is to supply required user info within token itself, so i can steel have my REST service completely stateless?

Comment: yes you are right, since it is stateless, your token should be able to provide information you need to do processing at server side

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!